# Invalid bean definition: Could not resolve placeholder

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I'm using `springframework` first time. So wrote a small program and to test value of Instance variable generated in IoC. But I am getting below error:

```
Feb 24, 2019 10:40:13 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'loadingObject' defined in class path resource [Spring-Config.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'log4j.configuration' in value "${log4j.configuration}"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'log4j.configuration' in value "${log4j.configuration}"
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'loadingObject' defined in class path resource [Spring-Config.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'log4j.configuration' in value "${log4j.configuration}"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'log4j.configuration' in value "${log4j.configuration}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:213)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:86)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:286)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:691)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:528)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
    at com.jcg.spring.log4j.Mainclass.main(Mainclass.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'log4j.configuration' in value "${log4j.configuration}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:172)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:124)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer$PlaceholderResolvingStringValueResolver.resolveStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:232)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveStringValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitPropertyValues(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitBeanDefinition(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:225)
    ... 9 more
```

I've placed my `application.properties` file and `Spring-Config.xml` metadata file to this location `...\src\main\resources`

application.properties

```
log4j.configuration=C:\Softwares\ConfigFiles\log4j.properties
```

Spring-Config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="propertiesToBeTaken" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath*:application.properties</value>
                <value>classpath*:*keys.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id = "loadingObject" class = "com.jcg.spring.log4j.TestController">
        <property name="log4jConfig" value="${log4j.configuration}" />
    </bean> 

</beans>
```

Code Snippet

```
public class TestController  {

    public String log4jConfig;

    public void setlog4j(String log4jConfig){

        this.log4jConfig = log4jConfig;

    }

    public  String getlog4j(){

        return this.log4jConfig;
    }

}

public class Mainclass {

    public static void main(String[] args){


        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-Config.xml");
        TestController obj = (TestController) context.getBean("TestController");
        System.out.println(obj.log4jCongif);



    }

}
```

Everything seems to be okay, But not sure why this error is coming.
Stuck in this for a while. Can anyone please have a look? What I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: do you have this property in application. properties `log4j.configuration`?

Comment: @Deadpool, Yes..I've mentioned in question as well...! Please check ..!

Comment: remove * after classpath in Spring-Config.xml

Comment: @AtulDwivedi, Same error after removing * ..!

Comment: @AtulDwivedi, Deadpool  Is there anything I can try....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems Spring container is trying to instantiate `TestController` bean before the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` so property is not getting resolved, hence the error.

You can try putting `<property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>` into Spring-Config.xml to tell spring to ignore unresolved properties. Once `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` will be instantiated possibly property will get resolved.

Try this

```
<bean id="propertiesToBeTaken" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:application.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:keys.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Plus few more changes:

- `TestController obj = (TestController) context.getBean("loadingObject");`
- setter method name: setLog4jConfig
- getter method name: getLog4jConfig

Comment: Now getting this error "Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'log4jConfig' of bean class [com.jcg.spring.log4j.TestController]: Bean property 'log4jConfig' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?"

Comment: Change setter method name to setLog4jConfig and getter method name to getLog4jConfig

Comment: Now its "Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'TestController' available" This shouldn't happen..Its there in xml...!

Comment: See my answer I've suggested few more changes

Comment: Thanks..You broke the Ice...!  But when am printing "obj.log4jConfig"why its giving me ${log4j.configuration} Instead of the value of log4j.configuration from application.properties file ...?

Comment: Now to get the actual value which has been placed in property file you need to make sure property file is in classpath so that spring can pick it. Currently it seems from resources folder spring is not able to pick it. Just try placing properties files in src folder. Remember it is not good practice to keep files in src.

Comment: If am placing application.properties file apart from src folder..Its saying file not found exception...!

Comment: You need to set resources folder as project resource folder then stuff inside that folder will be placed in classpath after building the project. Now it depends on you project structure and it's configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing PropertyPlaceHolder Bean with:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">

        <property name="location">
            <value>application.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```